# Flow on invariant Lagrangian tori

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, riemannian-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, geodesics

The most concrete version of the question is :

*A (necessarily) invariant Lagrangian torus $L$ on the unit cotangent of a Riemannian metric on the two-torus carries a periodic orbit with period $T$. Is it true  that every orbit on $L$ is periodic of period $T$?*

How about if we also assume that $L$ is a graph?

A more fanciful version of the question is whether there are any obstructions to a flow on a torus $L$ to be realized as the restriction of a Hamiltonian flow to an invariant Lagrangian torus.